# Looking for non-Boost::Python C++ Python embedding framework

Tags: c++, python, python-embedding

I have a project of mine, written in C++, that has now progressed to a stage where I require an embedded programming language. I've chosen Python for several reasons, and have been playing around with revealing an API to a dynamically-loaded Python module. It works well, and I think I will stick with Python for the foreseeable future.

I have a question, though. I've been spending a *lot* of time adding each function to the Python API that I'm providing, and so I've been looking for a framework that alleviates much of the repetition.

The framework that seems to be mentioned time and time again is Boost::Python. While I have nothing against Boost::Python -- in fact I will probably use it in the near future -- for this project I unfortunately cannot use Boost-related libraries.

Are there any other decent frameworks out there? I don't particularly fancy writing my own, but neither do I wish to continue my use of the straight Python C API.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share why you can't use "boost-related libraries"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing nearly the same problem but at the end I sticked `Boost::Python` ;) However an option to `Boost::Python` is [Swig](http://www.swig.org/doc.html). If you use [Swig](http://www.swig.org/doc.html) you also, don't have to write so much boilerplate code than you have to with `Boost::Python`.

Comment: Thanks! Swig looks exactly like what I was looking for.